# Exercise 1.1.10 from Murty's Problems in Analytic Number Theory

Tags: analytic-number-theory

The question is

> Suppose that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty d_3(k)|f(kx)|<\infty,$$
>
> where $d_3(k)$ denotes the number of factorizations of $k$ as a product of three numbers. Show that if $$g(x)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty f(mx),$$ then $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n)g(nx)$$ and conversely.

I don't see how to prove that $$\sum_{m,n} g(mnx)$$ converges absolutely, which we need to show the converse statement in the exercise. The solution in the book says it follows from the convergence of $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty d_3(k)|f(kx)|<\infty,$$ but I don't see how to do this without assuming $$g(x)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty f(mx),$$ which would be circular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry, your reasoning is correct.  The converse is definitely false.

Let $g(x)=\frac{1}{x},$  so that  $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(k)g(kx)=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(k)}{k}=0.$$ Then $f(x)=0,$ and hence the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}d_{3}(k)|f(kx)|$ converges, and equals $0$. However, we obviously don't have $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f(kx)=g(x).$$ To have the converse, we must assume that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}d_{2}(k)|g(kx)|<\infty,$$ and the condition $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}d_{3}(k)|f(kx)|$ is only sufficient in the forward direction. In the case above, the series did in fact diverge since $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}d_{2}(k)|g(kx)|=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{d_{2}(k)}{k}\gg\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}.$$

Comment: Recently I have also noticed this mistake. I will request him to correct it when he is coming to our institute tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks! Aside, don't we just need the condition $\sum_{k=1}^\infty d_2(k)|f(kx)|<\infty$ in the forward direction? (And using $d_2$ here is the same as using $d$, right?)

Comment: I really don't get why the summation is equal to zero.